# NSOperationQueue block updates UI before previous task finishes

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I need to complete following tasks in order and update UI after all the task are completed. 
Since data is depended on each other I have created `NSOperationQueue *myQueue` but one of the tasks taking so long to complete meanwhile last task is not waiting for previous task to finish and just updating the `UI`

Task order should be
1.Show Loading hub
2.Parse html get ids
3.Download Json with the parsed ids
4.populate database with json
  4.1 This part also has a lot of background work populating database takes about 5-6 seconds.
5.Hide loading hub

So 5 is executed before 4 and 4.1 finishes....
basically I want this [Serial](http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Serial-Queue.png) but this is happening I guess [Concurrent](http://cdn3.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Concurrent-Queue-480x272.png)
I have also tried 'dispatch_sync' no luck

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //show hud
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showLoadingHud) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];
    [self startProcess];

}

-(void)startProcess
{
    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];
    [myQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];

    __block NSMutableArray *imdbIDs=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSMutableArray *urlList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[ImdbURLs getImdburlArray]];

    NSBlockOperation *getiImdbViaHtmlParser = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    __weak NSBlockOperation *weakHtmlParser = getiImdbViaHtmlParser;

    [weakHtmlParser addExecutionBlock:^{
        //first
        for (NSString *imdbUrl in urlList) {
           ...
    }];

    NSBlockOperation *getJsonFromIMDB = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    __weak NSBlockOperation *weakGetJsonFromIMDB = getJsonFromIMDB ;

    [weakGetJsonFromIMDB  addExecutionBlock:^{
        //second
        for (NSString *imdbStrings in imdbIDs) {
                //this also calls database methods and populates database with safe threads
                [self AFReqTest:imdbStrings];//I guess this causing the problem
        }
    }];

    NSBlockOperation *checkResult = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    __weak NSBlockOperation *weakCheckResult = checkResult ;

    [weakCheckResult addExecutionBlock:^{
            //dismiss hud
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self dismissLoadingHud];//this is getting called before getJsonFromIMDB block finishes
            }];
    }];

    [checkResult addDependency:getJsonFromIMDB];
    [getJsonFromIMDB  addDependency:getiImdbViaHtmlParser];

    [myQueue addOperation:getJsonFromIMDB];
    [myQueue addOperation:getiImdbViaHtmlParser];
    [myQueue addOperation:checkResult];
}

-(void)AFReqTest:(NSString *)idString
{
    ...//buch of code
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

       //here I call another background method with result 
      [self insertIntoDatabase:responseObject];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}

-(void)insertIntoDatabase:(NSDictionary *)responseObject
{
    ParseImdbResponse *parse=[[ParseImdbResponse alloc] initWithResponseDic:responseObject];
    PopulateDatabase *inserInstance=[[PopulateDatabase alloc] initWithResponseDic:parse];

    dispatch_queue_t insertqueue= dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_sync(insertqueue, ^{
        [inserInstance inserIntoMoviesTable];
    });
    dispatch_sync(insertqueue, ^{
        [inserInstance inserIntoGenresTable];
    });
    dispatch_sync(insertqueue, ^{
        [inserInstance inserIntoActorsTable];
    });
    dispatch_sync(insertqueue, ^{
        [inserInstance inserIntoDirectorsTable];
    });
    dispatch_sync(insertqueue, ^{
        [inserInstance inserIntoMovieGenresTable];
    });
    dispatch_sync(insertqueue, ^{
        [inserInstance inserIntoMovieCastTable];
    });

}
```

Sorry for the long code I am not sure problem is my code structure or am I missing something?

Comment: Side note - no need for the use of `performSelectorOnMainThread` in `viewDidAppear:`. `viewDidAppear:` is always called on the main thread.

Comment: Why are you adding all of your operations to the main queue?

Comment: Missed that part should be `[NSOperationQueue new];` right?

Comment: All of your long processing should be on a background queue. Then do the UI update on the main queue.

Comment: I know thats the question actually before `NSOperationQueue` I also tried to create `dispatch_sync` but queue but it was also updating UI before task 4 finishes

Comment: Besides using the main queue instead of a background queue, your main issue is that the call to `AFReqTest:` returns immediately, long before the completion block is called. You need to refactor the code so the `checkResult` block isn't called until the completion block inside `AFReqTest:` is done. That's complicated by the fact that you call that method in a loop.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks, You are right, lesson learned hard way. I used nsnotifications to check if 4.1 is finished and dismiss loading hub.